# Why don't different bars share the same y-axis in plotly.express group bars

Tags: plot, graph, plotly, plotly-python

I made these attached group bars with plotly.express:
[image]

And my code is like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([['C-1','C-11','111'],['C-1','C-12','121'],['C-1','C-13','31'],['C-1','C-14','120'],['C-1','C-15','100'],
      ['C-2','C-21','150'],['C-2','C-22','168'],['C-2','C-23','173'],['C-2','C-24','111'],['C-2','C-25','121'],
      ['C-3','C-31','123'],['C-3','C-32','100'],['C-3','C-33','111'],['C-3','C-34','111'],['C-3','C-35','163'],
      ['C-4','C-41','174'],['C-4','C-42','174'],['C-4','C-43','173'],['C-4','C-44','135'],['C-4','C-45','102'],
      ['C-5','C-51','118'],['C-5','C-52','122'],['C-5','C-53','113'],['C-5','C-54','178'],['C-5','C-55','142']
      ],columns=['Case group','Case number','Average revenue']) 

import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(df,
      x='Case number',y='Average revenue',
      color='Case group', barmode='group',text="Average revenue",
      height=500,width=700,
      color_discrete_sequence=[px.colors.qualitative.Dark2[0],px.colors.qualitative.Set2[1],px.colors.qualitative.Pastel[0],px.colors.qualitative.Set2[5],px.colors.qualitative.Set2[4],])
      )
fig.update_traces(textposition='outside')
fig.show()
```

My question is, how can I make the y-axis labels normally ascend so that all groups share the same y-axis scale? e.g., C-55 should be lower than C-54 in my ideal thought.
Also, the annotations above each bar are too small to read. I tried to change the font size with `fig.update.layout()`. but it didn't work.

Please let me know if I did anything wrong.

I would really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to convert the column type to `float` as follows:

```
df["Average revenue"] = df["Average revenue"].astype(float)
```

**The full code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df=pd.DataFrame([['C-1','C-11','111'],['C-1','C-12','121'],['C-1','C-13','31'],['C-1','C-14','120'],['C-1','C-15','100'],
      ['C-2','C-21','150'],['C-2','C-22','168'],['C-2','C-23','173'],['C-2','C-24','111'],['C-2','C-25','121'],
      ['C-3','C-31','123'],['C-3','C-32','100'],['C-3','C-33','111'],['C-3','C-34','111'],['C-3','C-35','163'],
      ['C-4','C-41','174'],['C-4','C-42','174'],['C-4','C-43','173'],['C-4','C-44','135'],['C-4','C-45','102'],
      ['C-5','C-51','118'],['C-5','C-52','122'],['C-5','C-53','113'],['C-5','C-54','178'],['C-5','C-55','142']
      ],columns=['Case group','Case number','Average revenue']) 

df["Average revenue"] = df["Average revenue"].astype(float)

fig = px.bar(df,
      x="Case number",y='Average revenue',
      color='Case group', barmode='group',text="Average revenue",
      height=500,width=700,
      color_discrete_sequence=[px.colors.qualitative.Dark2[0],px.colors.qualitative.Set2[1],px.colors.qualitative.Pastel[0],px.colors.qualitative.Set2[5],px.colors.qualitative.Set2[4],])

fig.update_traces(textposition='outside', width=0.8)
fig.show()
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Still confused about the font size. It's good to interact with the zoom button 'online', but hard to read the annotations when I output it as .png.

Comment: @MattD626 You mean it is hard to read the Cs (x-axis tick labels) when you save the image as png?

Comment: @MattD626 , I understood your problem now, because it was not clear in the question. Anyway, I updated my answer :)

Comment: Thank you again! I also updated my unclear question about the font size part.